# Statistical test of fairness of partitioning

Tags: hypothesis-testing, partitioning

I have a question about a statistical test, but I lack the proper terminology so I'll try to explain in my own words.

Say I have a collection of $N$ objects. The collection is partitioned into $p$ chunks of $n$ objects each (so $N = np$). I do not have access to the method of chunking but I would like to know if it is fair in the following sense.

Each object has a numerical score. I determine a threshold and count the number of elements of each chunk that are above that threshold. These counts are $x_1, ..., x_p$. What statistical test can I apply to these counts which might tell me whether the chunking method is fair or biased?

Comment: How do you "determine" the threshold?  Do you plan to apply your test to multiple values of this threshold?  This is important to know, because any solution that is valid for a single threshold *that is determined independently of the data* will not be valid when applied to multiple thresholds or to a threshold you decide upon after reviewing the data.

Comment: @whuber Interesting. The problem arose because one value of the threshold gave the impression that the partitioning was fair but another value made it appear biased. These thresholds were determined independently of the data, not upon review.

Answer (score 0):

You can use goodness of fit chi square test.

Let $\bar x = \frac 1 p \sum _{i=1}^px_i$.

$S=\sum_{i=1}^p (x_i-\bar x)^2$

Then $$ \chi^2 = \frac S {\bar x} +\frac S{n-\bar x}$$ follows chi square distribution with $q-1$ degree of freedom asymptotically.